# Why can't C++ Builder find my headers?

Tags: c++, compilation, c++builder

I am required to recompile a C++ builder project, and am come across this problem.

one of the unit contains the followings:

```
#include    "LMDBaseControl.hpp"
#include    "LMDBaseGraphicControl.hpp"
#include    "LMDBaseLabel.hpp"
#include    "LMDBaseMeter.hpp"
#include    "LMDControl.hpp"
```

:

When I compiled this unit, I got the following error messages:

> MHSS_ISS_HMI_v3_2.cpp(41): #include
>   ....\include\MHSS\iss_hmi_gui_cached.h
>   [C++ Error] iss_hmi_gui_cached.h(68):
>   E2209 Unable to open include file
>   'LMDBaseControl.hpp'

Full parser context

> MHSS_ISS_HMI_v3_2.cpp(41): #include
>   ....\include\MHSS\iss_hmi_gui_cached.h
>   [C++ Error] iss_hmi_gui_cached.h(69):
>   E2209 Unable to open include  file
>   'LMDBaseGraphicControl.hpp'

Full parser context

> MHSS_ISS_HMI_v3_2.cpp(41): #include
>   ....\include\MHSS\iss_hmi_gui_cached.h
>   [C++ Error] iss_hmi_gui_cached.h(70):
>   E2209 Unable to open include file
>   'LMDBaseLabel.hpp'

Full parser context

> MHSS_ISS_HMI_v3_2.cpp(41): #include
>   ....\include\MHSS\iss_hmi_gui_cached.h
>   [C++ Error] iss_hmi_gui_cached.h(71):
>   E2209 Unable to open include file
>   'LMDBaseMeter.hpp'
>
> MHSS_ISS_HMI_v3_2.cpp(41): #include
>   ....\include\MHSS\iss_hmi_gui_cached.h
>   [C++ Error] iss_hmi_gui_cached.h(72):
>   E2209 Unable to open include file
>   'LMDControl.hpp' :

I have installed LMD Tools 7.0 on my Borland C++ builder 6, and set the library to the folder where I installed the LMD Tool.

Comment: Have you checked these hpp files present in the include path.. if not try searching for them in the all include directories..its quite unlikely that they are present looking at the errors

Comment: Just from memory (I no longer user LMD) you need to point your include path to a subdirectory of the LMD tools directory.  If you open the LMD tools directory with Windows Explorer it should be fairly obvious which one it should be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add both the path to the library and the path to the H files (2 separate options in the Borland options dialog).

Answer (score 2):

Fix your include paths for your project.  Did you only add the library path for the linker and not the include path for the compiler?  This is a pretty straightforward error.